# Smarty Error : unrecognized tag 'function'

Tags: php, smarty

Here is my code, I want to define a function in smarty.

```
{function name=menu level=0}
<ul class="level{$level}">
{foreach $data as $entry}
{if is_array($entry)}
<li>{$entry@key}</li>
{menu data=$entry level=$level+1}
{else}
<li>{$entry}</li>
{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
{/function}
```

But here is error i am getting , can someone please help ?

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in components/scripts.tpl line 1]:
syntax error: unrecognized tag 'function' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590)
in D:\xampp\htdocs\local_games\layout\default\php\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1095
```

Answer (score 2):

`{function}` is [Smarty3-specific](http://www.smarty.net/v3_overview), but you are probably using Smarty2